# Is it possible to make a Category page the homepage in magento?

Tags: php, magento

I would like to display a catergory page as my homepage rather than a CMS page as it seems to be difficult to get a CMS page to properly display items.

I have gone to

> Url rewrite Management

and created a url-rewrite for a category

Then gone to

> System|Configuration|Web|Default Pages|

and changed

> Default Web URL

to my new url-rewrite from cms but I get a 404 error when I go to the root of my site.  Is there a way to redirect the root to a category rather than a CMS page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just add this to any CMS page (substitute the category ID that you want to display - you can find that in Admin->Catalog->Manage categories):

```
 {{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="8" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Comment: I did this, but the css gets all mucked up, I just want to change the homepage.

Answer (score 11):

Here is an easier way to do it. Find out first the ID of the category. Then you go to "System > Configuration > Web > Default Pages" and enter the following for the "Default web url" option: catalog/category/view/id/50 (where 50 is the id of the category).

Note, in version 1.3.2.4 there is a bug in one of the core files. So if you use that see this fix first: http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue?issue=6168

Answer (score 1):

The idea with

> "Default web url" option: catalog/category/view/id/50 (where 50 is the id of the category).

works very well also in version 1.9.2.4, but navigating to page 2 there is the name of the category missing:

domain.com//p/2

Answer (score 0):

This is only a hint.

You'll have to edit or create a new page in the cms. then go to design tab and update the layout xml with a category information. Never done this but by looking at default home xml I guess this can be done. It could look something like this, but this is invented so you'll have to research.

```
<block type="catalog/category" name="home.catalog.category.5" alias="categ_5" template="catalog/category/id/5" after="cms_page">
   <action method="addPriceBlockType">
   <type>bundle</type>
</block>
```